# Interrupting Evaluate?

Tags: gurps-4e, gurps

Let's say I spend a turn doing an Evaluate maneuver, focusing on one enemy. Can anything happen (taking damage, getting stunned or prone, etc) which would cause me to lose the bonus modifier before I get to use it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK Evaluate has no explicit conditions that will cause the bonus to be lost, but it is also a minimally-described rule, so I would say it is very ripe for reasonable GM rulings and house rules to develop it.

There are of course many situations which will prevent or discourage the bonus from being used, which are much more apparent if you are playing with a hex map with terrain and so on (as opposed to playing without a map), because there are many things which will prevent someone from being able to make an attack in the next turn (that players who don't use maps might not think of), such as:

- Just step further away during your turn. In many situations, you'll be able to increase the range so that if he wants his +1 bonus next turn, he'll have to do something rash and unwise like Move & Attack or even All Out Attack, which result in other tactical problems.
- Use Move to get too far away from him to attack you next turn.
- If you are attacked on your turn when someone is Evaluating you, consider using a Retreat to step further away from the Evaluator. This can either put you out of range of his next attack, or put you someplace where it's not a good move for him to come after you.
- Have some obstacle appear between you - either a friend or foe, or a fallen body, or close a door or push over some furniture or something, so he either won't be able to reach you next turn, or will have to overcome the obstacle to do so.
- Stand in a place so that if he does move to attack you, he needs to be in a tactically problematic place to do so, such as on broken ground, or in a place where your friends will be able to hit him. If you and them are Waiting with ready hand weapons, the guy stalking you will need to face all of your waiting attacks if he wants to get his +1.
- All-Out Defend, so that he gets his +1, but you get even better defenses.
- Feint, so that he's afraid to come attack you because you may defend and then nail him.
- Enter close combat with him in such a way that he can't use his weapon (various ways to do this - grapple, slam, tackle, or just move so that he can't back up to get to a reach where he can use his weapon, if the situation allows).
- Knock him down, so he can't reach you or will at best have to claw at you from the ground with his +1 if the GM rules he still gets his +1.
- Stun him so he's liable to lose his next action.
- Disarm or unready his weapon so he can't attack you next turn.
- Injure him so (he may fall or be stunned or crippled, and) he will have a shock penalty which will counter the +1 or be even more.
- Knock him unconscious or kill him.
- Anything else that keeps him from getting to you, getting to you effectively, or wanting to get to you, next turn.

In addition to all of those counter-moves, the GM would be reasonable IMO to also rule that yes the +1 is lost if any of the following happen:

- Evaluator falls down.
- Evaluator is stunned.
- Evaluator enters close combat with someone else.
- Evaluator can't see the target at the start of his next turn.

Answer (score 1):

Dronz's answer is good, but complicated. Since Evaluate says that it's the melee combat equivalent of Aim, I'd apply the Aim rules, except where the Evaluate description differs.

So unlike Aim, an Evaluator can use an active defence without losing his Evaluate bonus, but if he's injured, he has to make a Will roll or lose the bonus. And of course, anything that makes the Evaluator unable or unwilling to attack is an effective countermeasure.

My impression is that Evaluate mostly gets used when the defender is unaware of the attacker, and there isn't short-term time pressure. Under those conditions, doing three Evaluates and then a Step and Attack is a good way to re-create the "backstab" trope.